# Unable to uninstall or remove adware "Browser Shop" from browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, windows-registry, google-chrome-extensions, adware

few days ago i opted for auto-installation of some software and i believe this adware was installed along with it.

I uninstalled the software and did removed this adware extension from chrome, also i uninstalled all the suspicious program listed in add/remove program. I also used adware removal tool and i had success in removing two other adwares named like pricechop.

If there is anything else i can do like deleting some registry entries or other ways. Please help me out! This adware is really annoying me!

P.S.: I hate advertisements, when i am doing something important on the internet.

Comment: Scan your system using [AdwCleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/) and report back.

Answer (score 3):

Source [Ads by Browser Shop Removal Guide](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-browser-shop-virus/)

> Browser Shop is an adware program, that displays pop-up ads and advertisements on web pages that you visit. These advertisements will be shown as boxes containing various coupons that are available, as underlined keywords, pop-up ads or advertising banners.
>
> This page is a comprehensive guide, which will remove “Browser Shop”
>   virus from your computer, and any other adware program that may have
>   been installed during the setup process. Please perform all the steps
>   in the correct order. If you have any questions or doubt at any point,
>   STOP and ask for our assistance.
>
> 1. Uninstall Browser Shop from Windows
> 2. Remove “Ads by Browser Shop” virus from Internet Explorer, Firefox and Google Chrome
> 3. Remove Browser Shop adware from Internet Explorer, Firefox and Google Chrome with AdwCleaner
> 4. Remove Browser Shop browser hijacker with Junkware Removal Tool
> 5. Remove “Ads by Browser Shop” virus with Malwarebytes Anti-Malware Free
> 6. Double-check for the “Browser Shop” malware with HitmanPro

Each of the above steps has detailed instructions and screenshots.

Comment: These steps worked for me, though HitmanPro's free license expires after 30 days so for most people it's good for one clean unless you purchase it (not saying you shouldn't, just don't expect to use it for free a second time down the road ;)